# AttributeError: AS Instance has no attribute 'toString'

Tags: python, arrays, function, a-star

Writing code in Python for an Astar program to find the shortest path between cities.  Getting the above error, and I'm at a complete loss.  Pulling between a few .py files, here are the relevant sections:

from asdriver.py - ***added full asdriver***

```
import adata   # Map data
import astar   # A* class
import sys

# Default start, goal cities
defaultcities = ('Yakima, WA', 'Tampa, FL')

def printnode(n):
    print n.toString()

adata.input()

startcity = raw_input("Start city [{0}]: ".format(defaultcities[0])).strip()
if startcity == '':  startcity = defaultcities[0]
if startcity not in adata.cities:
     print "City not recognized"
     sys.exit(0)

goalcity = raw_input("Goal city [{0}]: ".format(defaultcities[1])).strip()
if goalcity == '':  goalcity = defaultcities[1] 
if goalcity not in adata.cities:
    print "City not recognized"
    sys.exit(0)

dbg = raw_input("Debug Options: [none]").strip()

findpath = astar.AS(startcity, goalcity, printnode)
ans = findpath.astar_run(printnode, dbg)
    if not ans:
        print "No answer"
    else:
        print "Final Path:"
        print ans.toString()
```

From astar.py

```
 import adata

 class AS:
     def __init__(self, startcity, goalcity, tracefunc):
        self.startcity = startcity
        self.goalcity = goalcity
        self.tracefunc = tracefunc
        self.openlist = [Node([startcity])]
        self.closedlist = []

     def heuristic(self, printnode, start, end):
        raise NotImplementedError

     def astar_run(self, startcity, endcity, dbg = ""):
        while self.openlist:
            citystep = min(self.openlist, key = lambda o:o.g + o.h)
            if citystep == self.goalcity:
                 path = []
                 while citystep.parent:
                path.append(citystep)
                citystep = citystep.parent
            path.append(citystep)
            return path[::-1]
        self.openlist.remove(citystep)
        self.closedlist.append(citystep)
        for printnode in self.openlist:   #was self.tracefunc
            if printnode in self.closedset:
                continue
            elif printnode in self.openset:
                newG = citystep.g + citystep.cost(printnode)
                if printnode.g > newG:
                    printnode.g = newG
                    printnode.parent = citystep
                else:
                    printnode.g = citystep.g + citystep.cost(printnode)
                    printnode.h = self.heuristic(printnode, start, end)
                    printnode.parent = citystep
                    self.openset.add(printnode)
        return self    



class Node:
def __init__(self, path=[], f=0, g=0, h=0):
    self.path = path[:]
    self.f = f
    self.g = g
    self.h = h
    self.parent = None

def toString(self):
    s = 'f=%d g=%d h=%d ' % (self.f, self.g, self.h)
    for city in self.path:
        s = s + ' ' + city
    return s

def cost(self):
    raise NotImplementedError
```

'

Complete beginner, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Your indentation is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `def astar_run()` method returns `self` (see last line of your method), or it returns a list by slicing the `path[::-1]`, neither has a `toString()` method so you are getting this exception. If you want to print the representation of your class then it is normal to declare this method `__repr__()` and then you can just `print ans`. If you want to be able to convert to a string then the method is usually called `__str__()`.

What do you expect to be return from `astar_run()`? It is usually poor practice to return two different types from the same function.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I want Astar_run to return the shortest path from the startcity to the goalcity.  Indentation for Node class is correct in the .py, I just inserted it into the post incorrectly.  As for __repr__(), would I declare it in astar.py or asdriver.py?  It occurs to me that I should probably have posted the entirety of asdriver for reference.... I'll edit it into the post.  Thanks again.

Comment: You would define it as a class method for any class that you wanted to print, e.g. it would be a replacement for Node.toString. If you are expecting a list of Node back from the `astar_run()` then you are returning the wrong thing at the end of `astar_run()`, presumably you need some list back maybe `self.openset`? In your asdriver.py you will need to iterate over the result of `astar_run()`, e.g. `for i in ans: print i.toString()` or `for i in ans: print i` if you change `Node.toString()` to `Node.__repr__()`